# Normal Distribution given mean and standard deviation

Tags: sas

I want to generate a normal distribution in SAS and I have the mean and standard deviation, but do NOT have any data. I am trying to distribute 100 samples according to the standard deviation. I am not sure what functions to use.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say mean is 50 and std is 5, this will generate 20 samples of 100 each that follow that distribution.

```
data want;
call streaminit(1);
do sample=1 to 20;
    do n=1 to 100;
        x=rand('normal', 50, 5);
        output;
    end;
end;
run;
```

Using `call streaminit` is optional, but if you don't, you'll get different results each time the code is run as SAS will use the system time to generate a seed.